# Pull data from html javascript nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, node.js

I'm working on making a CLI for google searches for myself, and I've been using nodejs for a little while working on a chatbot, so I'd like to get it working with nodejs. I can pull the data just fine, and end up with a string that has all the html data from the page. It's even easy to sort out in the html what the results that I want are:

```
<div class="jd"><a class="p" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://leagueoflegends.com/&amp;ved=0CBAQFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNEEnWGHwxNnuwKenqm4ajKfTM6Xxw" ><b>League of Legends</b> - Free Online Game | <b>LoL</b> - <b>League of Legends</b></a> </div> <div class="kd">3 days ago&nbsp;… Official website for <b>League of Legends</b>. Join millions of players in an award   winning Multiplayer Online Battle Arena. </div> <div class="qdlmxn"><a class="gg" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://leagueoflegends.com/board&amp;ved=0CBEQ0gIoADAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNHpmmAdFFbTgm8C_gJvsjVhMzVKUQ" >Community</a> - <a class="gg" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://signup.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup/redownload&amp;ved=0CBIQ0gIoATAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFHGUtn4ItgQIzODgIZRv_237Mq0A" >PVP.NET</a> - <a class="gg" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/forumdisplay.php?f%3D2&amp;ved=0CBMQ0gIoAjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNHpycJ8WGh7xvWw1qNu8NjjU1EA0Q" >General Discussion</a> - <a class="gg" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://na.leagueoflegends.com/champions&amp;ved=0CBQQ0gIoAzAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNEpeBzNefwag5xmkFcFhCW27FoAew" >Champions</a> </div><span class="c">leagueoflegends.com/</span> -  <div class="txnles" onclick="_popup('web_result_popup_10836585','inline');"> <div class="wx4xyp" id="web_result_popup_10836585"> <div class="vfc7iu"><a class="s" href="/search?q=cache:GCRD1wy5e3QJ:leagueoflegends.com/" >Cached</a> <br/><a class="s" href="/m/?q=related:leagueoflegends.com/&amp;ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;ved=0CBYQHzAA" >Similar</a> <br/><a class="s" href="/gwt/x?q=lol&amp;ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;hl=en&amp;source=m&amp;u=http://leagueoflegends.com/" >Mobile formatted</a> </div> </div><a class="s" href="javascript:void(0)" >Options</a> <div class="m6u8fq"> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div> <div class="r ld"> <div class="jd"><a class="p" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOL&amp;ved=0CBgQFjAB&amp;usg=AFQjCNFOhgg5Y2E5SFuS5I-8830OJ9VR9Q" ><b>LOL</b> - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a> </div> <div class="kd"><b>LOL</b>, an abbreviation for <b>laughing out loud</b>, or <b>laugh out loud</b>, is a common   element of Internet slang. It was used historically on Usenet&nbsp;… </div><span class="c">en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOL</span> -  <div class="txnles" onclick="_popup('web_result_popup_30597472','inline');"> <div class="wx4xyp" id="web_result_popup_30597472"> <div class="vfc7iu"><a class="s" href="/search?q=cache:mhIpOeXQp38J:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOL" >Cached</a> <br/><a class="s" href="/m/?q=related:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOL&amp;ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;ved=0CBkQHzAB" >Similar</a> <br/><a class="s" href="/gwt/x?q=lol&amp;ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;hl=en&amp;source=m&amp;u=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOL" >Mobile formatted</a> </div> </div><a class="s" href="javascript:void(0)" >Options</a> <div class="m6u8fq"> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div> <div class="r ld">
```

Anything that is .jd is a result, so I first need to separate those out, then working on getting the URLs and the Descriptions separated out, too. I've never done string manipulation to this extreme, so I've got no idea where to start with this.

Here's the html in a more readable format, realize though that I'm dealing with just one long string.

```
<div>
  <div class="r ld">
    <div class="jd">
      <a class="p" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://leagueoflegends.com/&amp;ved=0CBAQFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNEEnWGHwxNnuwKenqm4ajKfTM6Xxw" >
        <b>League of Legends</b> - Free Online Game | <b>LoL</b> - <b>League of Legends</b>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="kd">
      3 days ago&nbsp;… Official website for <b>League of Legends</b>. Join millions of players in an award   winning Multiplayer Online Battle Arena. 
    </div>
    <div class="qdlmxn">
      <a class="gg" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://leagueoflegends.com/board&amp;ved=0CBEQ0gIoADAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNHpmmAdFFbTgm8C_gJvsjVhMzVKUQ" >Community</a> - 
      <a class="gg" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://signup.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup/redownload&amp;ved=0CBIQ0gIoATAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFHGUtn4ItgQIzODgIZRv_237Mq0A" >PVP.NET</a> - 
      <a class="gg" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/forumdisplay.php?f%3D2&amp;ved=0CBMQ0gIoAjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNHpycJ8WGh7xvWw1qNu8NjjU1EA0Q" >General Discussion</a> - 
      <a class="gg" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://na.leagueoflegends.com/champions&amp;ved=0CBQQ0gIoAzAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNEpeBzNefwag5xmkFcFhCW27FoAew" >Champions</a> 
    </div>
    <span class="c">leagueoflegends.com/</span> -  
    <div class="txnles" onclick="_popup('web_result_popup_10836585','inline');">
      <div class="wx4xyp" id="web_result_popup_10836585"> <div class="vfc7iu">
        <a class="s" href="/search?q=cache:GCRD1wy5e3QJ:leagueoflegends.com/" >Cached</a> 
        <br/>
        <a class="s" href="/m/?q=related:leagueoflegends.com/&amp;ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;ved=0CBYQHzAA" >Similar</a> 
        <br/>
        <a class="s" href="/gwt/x?q=lol&amp;ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;hl=en&amp;source=m&amp;u=http://leagueoflegends.com/" >Mobile formatted</a> 
      </div> 
    </div>
    <a class="s" href="javascript:void(0)" >Options</a> 
    <div class="m6u8fq"> </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 
<div> 
  <div class="r ld"> 
    <div class="jd">
      <a class="p" href="/m/url?ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOL&amp;ved=0CBgQFjAB&amp;usg=AFQjCNFOhgg5Y2E5SFuS5I-8830OJ9VR9Q" >
        <b>LOL</b> - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="kd">
      <b>LOL</b>, an abbreviation for <b>laughing out loud</b>, or <b>laugh out loud</b>, is a common   element of Internet slang. It was used historically on Usenet&nbsp;… 
    </div>
    <span class="c">en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOL</span> -  
    <div class="txnles" onclick="_popup('web_result_popup_30597472','inline');"> 
      <div class="wx4xyp" id="web_result_popup_30597472"> 
        <div class="vfc7iu">
          <a class="s" href="/search?q=cache:mhIpOeXQp38J:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOL" >Cached</a> 
          <br/>
          <a class="s" href="/m/?q=related:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOL&amp;ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;ved=0CBkQHzAB" >Similar</a> 
          <br/>
          <a class="s" href="/gwt/x?q=lol&amp;ei=ZtZnT8CTOMy48AbDzgE&amp;hl=en&amp;source=m&amp;u=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOL" >Mobile formatted</a> 
        </div> 
      </div>
      <a class="s" href="javascript:void(0)" >Options</a> 
      <div class="m6u8fq"> </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why have you pasted a single, monstrous line of HTML? Do you think we can read that easily or something? Please format it into a usable state.

Comment: That's exactly what I get, that's what I'm working with. Why would post something that isn't relevant to the question?

Comment: why not use jsDom and manipulate the DOM nodes?

Comment: I'm planning on having this as a commandline tool, so I can just pop over to my terminal and say "google 'terms'" and have it return me results, and eventually move it to the chatbot.

Comment: @JamWaffles I don't see how being able to read it more easily will help, but there it is.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: @luxun I was under the impression that that api was limited IE not a true google search. Will do a bit more research

Comment: other means of programatically google searching are against the google search TOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luxun lead me back to the google API, and I found out how to search full web results instead of just included sites here: http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210656

```
To create a search engine that searches the entire web:

From the Google Custom Search homepage, click Create a Custom Search Engine.
Type a name and description for your search engine.
Under Define your search engine, in the Sites to Search box, enter at least one valid URL (e.g. www.google.com).
Select the CSE edition you want and accept the Terms of Service, then click Next. Select the layout option you want, and then click Next.
Click any of the links under the Next steps section to navigate to your Control panel.
In the left-hand menu, under Control Panel, click Basics.
In the Search Preferences section, select Search the entire web but emphasize included sites.
Click Save Changes.
In the left-hand menu, under Control Panel, click Sites.
Delete the site you entered during the initial setup process.
```

Answer (score 0):

so i was in kinda of same situation but with xml, and i created this html/xml parser for my own needs.

i tried to make it look like browser model of DOM manipulation so most of the things work the same way

First a Node just copy paste in your js file. dont forget to declare "use strict"; at the begining of the file.

```
class Node {
    constructor(nodeName, nodeType) {
        this.nodeName = nodeName;

        this.nodeType = nodeType;
        this.attributes = {};
        this.childNodes = [];
        this.parentNode = null;


    }

    removeChild(node) {
        if (node.parentNode != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
                if (node == this.childNodes[i]) {
                    this.childNodes.splice(i, 1);
                    node.parentNode = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    appendChild(child) {
        if (child.parentNode == null) {
            this.childNodes.push(child);
            child.parentNode = this;

        } else {
            child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
            this.childNodes.push(child);
            child.parentNode = this;

        }
    }

    returnMyChildNodes() {
        return this.childNodes;
    }

    returnElementCollection() {
        var array = [];
        array.push(this);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var tmparray = [];
            tmparray = this.childNodes[i].returnElementCollection();
            array = array.concat(tmparray);
        }

        return array;
    }

    getELementsByAttributeValue(attribute, value) {
        var matchedElements = [];
        var Elements = this.returnElementCollection();
        console.log(Elements.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < Elements.length; i++) {
            if (typeof Elements[i].attributes[attribute] != "undefined") {
                if (Elements[i].attributes[attribute] == value) {
                    matchedElements.push(Elements[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        return matchedElements;
    }

}
```

This node object will Act like html nodes. so we declare another class here.

```
class Html_Node extends Node {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name, "HTML_ELEMENT");
    }

    toString() {

    }
}

class Xml_Node extends Node {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name, "XML_ELEMENT");

        this.innerText = "";
    }

}
```

after we have classes for both we go to the hard part Read the document and build our nodes in 1 document

```
class XML_Reader {
    constructor() {
        this.rawContents = "";
        this.Document = null;
    }

    loadXML(documentPath) {
        if (documentPath != null && documentPath != "") {
            var fs = require("fs");
            var fc = fs.readFileSync(documentPath, {
                encoding: "utf-8"
            });
            if (typeof fc != "undefined" && fc != null) {
                this.rawContents = fc;
            } else {
                this.rawContents = null;
            }

            delete require.cache[require.resolve("fs")];
        } else {
            this.rawContents = null;
        }


    }

    processXML() {

        var XML_DOC = new Xml_Node("root");
        var rawElements = [];
        var TagStart_index = 0;
        var TagEnd_index = 0;

        var innerContent_Start = 0;
        var innerContent_End = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.rawContents.length; i++) {
            // get starting tags
            if (this.rawContents[i] == "<") {
                TagStart_index = i;
                innerContent_End = i - 1;

                var innerContent = "";
                if (innerContent_End > innerContent_Start) {
                    for (var n = innerContent_Start; n <= innerContent_End; n++) {
                        innerContent += this.rawContents[n];
                    }

                    if (/\S/.test(innerContent)) {
                        // do smth with innerContent of tag
                        rawElements.push(innerContent);
                    }
                }


            } else if (this.rawContents[i] == ">") {

                TagEnd_index = i;
                innerContent_Start = i + 1;
                var contents = "";

                for (var n = TagStart_index; n <= TagEnd_index; n++) {
                    contents += this.rawContents[n];
                }

                rawElements.push(contents);
            }

        }

        var currentParent = XML_DOC;
        for (var i = 0; i < rawElements.length; i++) {
            if (/>/.test(rawElements[i]) && /</.test(rawElements[i])) {
                if (rawElements[i].indexOf("/") == 1) {
                    currentParent = currentParent.parentNode;

                } else {
                    var str = rawElements[i];
                    str = str.replace("<", "");
                    str = str.replace(">", "");
                    var IgnoreSpace = false;
                    var tempString = "";
                    var InnerNodeContents = [];
                    var wordIndex = 0;
                    for (var n = 0; n < str.length; n++) {
                        if (!IgnoreSpace) {

                            if (str[n] == "/") {
                                InnerNodeContents[wordIndex] = tempString;
                                tempString = "";
                                wordIndex++;
                            }
                            if (n + 1 == str.length) {
                                tempString +=
                                    str[n];
                                InnerNodeContents[wordIndex] = tempString;
                                tempString = "";
                                wordIndex++;
                            } else if (!/\S/.test(str[n])) {
                                InnerNodeContents[wordIndex] = tempString;
                                tempString = "";
                                wordIndex++;
                            } else {
                                tempString += str[n];
                            }

                            if (str[n] == '"') IgnoreSpace = true;

                        } else {
                            if (str[n] == "/") {
                                InnerNodeContents[wordIndex] = tempString;
                                tempString = "";
                                wordIndex++;
                            }
                            if (n + 1 == str.length) {
                                tempString += str[n];
                                InnerNodeContents[wordIndex] = tempString;
                                tempString = "";
                                wordIndex++;
                            } else {
                                tempString += str[n];
                            }
                            if (str[n] == '"') IgnoreSpace = false;

                        }
                    }

                    var node = new Xml_Node(InnerNodeContents[0]);

                    // add attributes
                    var switchParent = false;

                    if (InnerNodeContents[InnerNodeContents.length - 1] == "/") {
                        switchParent = true;

                        for (var n = 1; n < InnerNodeContents.length - 1; n++) {
                            var tmparray = InnerNodeContents[n].split("=");
                            node.attributes[tmparray[0]] = tmparray[1].replaceAll('"', "");
                        }
                    } else {

                        for (var n = 1; n < InnerNodeContents.length; n++) {
                            var tmparray = InnerNodeContents[n].split("=");
                            node.attributes[tmparray[0]] = tmparray[1].replaceAll('"', "");
                        }
                    }

                    currentParent.appendChild(node);
                    if (!switchParent) currentParent = node;


                }
            } else {
                currentParent.innerText = rawElements[i];
            }

        }

        this.Document = XML_DOC;

    }

}
```

and then all we need to do is:

```
var xr = new XML_Reader();
xr.loadXML("Path to HTML file");
xr.processXML();

var Elements = xr.Document.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "jd");
```

and now u have Everysingle element with class of jd in that Element variable.

and then to get URL of each one you will do FOR loop and fetch href attribute

```
var myUrl = Elements[0].attributes.href;
```

i made this script for my self, so feel free to use it:)

one more thing. to get childs of DIV with class of JD u will need to get that div and search for nodeNames (a), and get heir href Attributes.